# Spring @Cachable: Not working on methods with parameters

Tags: java, spring, caching

I wanted to try the Spring 3.1 Cache Abstraction, annotating some methods with @Cachable. This is working just fine on methods without parameters. For methods with parameters it doesn't. Couldn't find anything in the docs (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html).

Anybody experiencing the same thing?

The method call is :

```
@Cachable("countries") 
public List<ConfigEntity> findCountries(Locale locale) { 
    ConfigSearchDescription desc = new ConfigSearchDescription(); 
    // ... 
    return findConfigs(desc); 
}
```

Thanks
Jonny

Comment: it works well, demonstrate your code please

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It's straight forward to the example code of the docs. The method call is : 
`  
@Cachable("countries") 
public List<ConfigEntity> findCountries(Locale locale) 
{ 
 ConfigSearchDescription desc = new ConfigSearchDescription(); 
 // ... return findConfigs(desc); 
} 
`

Comment: please add the code with proper format in your question, you can edit your question back

Comment: Sory for the inconvenience. I'm having a terrible time finding out how to format code on this board. I'll post it properly formatted as soon as I find out.

Comment: Are you calling this method from another method of the same bean? Remember that in this case proxies usually can't intercept these calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are you calling this method from another method of the same bean?
>   Remember that in this case proxies usually can't intercept these
>   calls.

This was my mistake.

Thanks all for your help

Comment: This took me 5 hours to find out. I guess the only solution here is to check if the cached key exists within the same method and return the value as an added check.